# error file location is not showing in my vs code debug console

Tags: debugging, console

In my debug console, I am not receiving the GetX routing path message as follows: "Instance "BottonNavController" has been initialize" and log() class is not printing. also not showing the exact error file location like the photo below. How can I solve this?

Now I want to solve these issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.